# Error with dandelion datatables - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: spring-mvc, datatable, dandelion

I have installed for the first time dandelion datatables. I followed [this](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.0.1/docs/html/) guide. I am using version 1.0.1

Can you help me to troubleshoot the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/jquery/js/jquery.js

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.js

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/datatables/features/filtering/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

`dandelion-datatables-91438756c71be2df6b2ee155197c3192.js:34`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/datatables/features/filtering/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/website/dandelion/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

http://localhost:8080/enepath/dandelion/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure to meet all requirements, in particular "Servlet 3.0+ container". Also ensure that your `web.xml` file is well configured for the Servlet 3.0 API:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
...
</web-app>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was using version 2.5. I changed it now but the error still persists. I am using spring 4.1 and tomcat 8

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the following to `mvc-core-config.xml` in order to expose dandelion's resources:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/dandelion/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/dandelion/" />
```